# PDF reader with option to search multiple words at the time/match any of the words

Tags: pdf, search

Are there any PDF readers with advanced search options -  **searching several words at a time** to be exact? Adobe has it by the name **match any of the words** as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/843309/can-i-somehow-search-few-words-at-the-same-timealternative-in-foxit-reader-or).

Regular (standard) search would acquire searching *dog*, viewing result, then *cat*, view result, then *monkey*... - which would mean I would go through entire file 3 times.

I wish to input a list of words (strings) *cat*, *dog*, *monkey*, *baby lion*, and as I go through results, one by one, have all of the matching strings displayed, requiring going trough entire file only once.

Another great option would be to search (in a described way)  in multiple files. I've read  **grep** can do that but, I wish my results were displayed in (pdf reader) GUI.

Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Okular**](https://okular.kde.org/) has this feature, under **Thumbnails Search** (which made it a bit hard to find since it is not in standard search). It highlights each word in a different color so you can see them scrolling through a file.

[image]

> DISCLAMER:  Doesn't work in case of "baby lion"

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about several words that appear one after another, then every pdf reader should do. Evince is one example. 
If you need something more exotic, then you must specify what do you want to do.

Comment: I don't think this can be done by one of the opensource pdf readers. I tried okular, atril, evince and libreoffice and i couldn't do it. I don't know if foxit can do something like that. As for adobe. They stopped supporting linux around 5 years ago and i don't know if it's even possible to download the last version of their reader.

Comment: Also try: https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/ I newer used it, but at least they are advertising advanced search feature.

Comment: I think I read one might be able to run Adobe with Wine. I'm not sure if older supported versions are offering  this option - will look into that. PDF studio is currently stuck installing... I hope I get to install it. In the meantime, I added  [feature request](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403514) to (my favorite PDF viewer) Okular.

Comment: Okular had it all along, and I've been using Okular for quite some time, not ever paying attention to Thumbnail search. @user1403360